# Pros/cons for using lua as a cross-platform language for SDK

Tags: android, ios, mobile, architecture, lua

I'm planning the development of a mobile SDK in the gaming field, that should be cross platform (iOS and Android to begin with)

I know that many game engines embed lua as a scripting language, to expose certain functionality easily to the developer, however i've never since it being used as the core language that SDKs are written in.

What are the pros/cons for using lua specifically for achieving a cross-platform mobile SDK?

Answer (score 3):

**Pros:**

- Portable: builds on any platform with an `ANSI C` compiler.
- `Lua` is comparably as easy as `Python` in terms of learning how to write code.
- [Embedded](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html) and extensible language that provides a straightforward interface to/from `C/C++/Objective-C`. It has a very clean `C API`.
- Sufficiently fast: performs well comparing to other languages and has a [`JIT`](http://luajit.org/performance.html) compiler that noticeably improves performance on many tasks.
- Well documented: [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/), [book](http://www.lua.org/pil/), [wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/), [6-page](http://www.capgo.com/Resources/SoftwareDev/LuaShortRef51.pdf) short reference and more.
- Friendly and enthusiastic [community](http://lua-users.org/).
- Clean and simple syntax suitable for beginners and accessible to non-programmers.
- Integrated interpreter: just run `lua` from the command line.
- Native support for coroutines to implement iterators and non-preemptive multi-threading.
- Incremental garbage collector that has low latency, no additional memory cost, little - implementation complexity, and support for weak tables.
- Simple yet powerful [debug library](http://www.lua.org/pil/23.html).
- Free

**Cons:**

- `Lua` does not focus on 100% backward compatibility. Many newer releases of `Lua` break programs written in previous versions.
- Limited [error handling](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.4.html) support.
- Global scoping by default.
- [No `Unicode`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaUnicode) support.
- `Lua` supports only a few data structures, including arrays, lists and hash tables.
- Limited [pattern-matching](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html) support.
- No `POSIX` functions built-in..
- No class/object finalizers.
- Packaging on Windows. It requires a fair amount of experience with Windows application packaging to produce an installer that provides everything your end user needs in a way that makes your use of `Lua` as the core language irrelevant to them.

Based on:

[Lua - Good, Different, Bad and Ugly parts.](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/programming/lua-good-different-bad-and-ugly-parts)

[Look at Lua](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9605?page=0,0)

Comment: good points, although some of them are not mobile related.